# Is the landowner being fair to all the workers in the Parable of the Workers of the Vineyard in Matthew 20?

Tags: matthew

Contemporary English Version Matthew 20:4

> He promised to pay them what was **fair**, if they would work in his vineyard.

NIV Matthew 20

> 8 “When evening came, the owner of the vineyard said to his foreman, ‘Call the workers and pay them their wages, beginning with the last ones hired and going on to the first.’
> 9 “The workers who were hired about five in the afternoon came and each received a denarius. 10So when those came who were hired first, they expected to receive more. But each one of them also received a denarius. 11When they received it, they began to grumble against the landowner. 12‘These who were hired last worked only one hour,’ they said, ‘and you have made them equal to us who have borne the burden of the work and the heat of the day.’
> 13“But he answered one of them, ‘I am **not being unfair** to you, friend.

Is the landowner being fair to all the workers or is he practicing favoritism? Is the word "fair" a suitable translation?

Comment: The Greek is αδικω σε ουχι _I do wrong you not_. Or _I do no unrighteousness to you_. [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/matthew/20-13.htm). [Strong 91](https://biblehub.com/greek/adiko__91.htm)

Comment: If a man accepts a job of work for an agreed rate of pay : what's unfair about that ?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem completely fair, as the workers seem unaware they could have worked just the last bit of the day and been paid the same. In this sense, they were misled by the landowner. If they had been aware of this, they probably wouldn't have worked the entire day, but just the last bit.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg Wouldn't a grateful employee be _happy_ to work the whole day rather than 'stand idle' ? To be productive, rather than unfruitful ? Does such an employee show _charity_ towards the employer offering work and hire ?

Comment: The meaning of the text is that the workers are not payed less than they would have otherwise earned.

Comment: @Lucian That doesn't make sense to me. Perhaps you could actually answer the question in full and I can consider your argument in full. Thank you.

Comment: @NigelJ: No man has ever accused his own client or employer of *unfairness* when being tipped by him. Oddly enough, that selfsame courtesy does not seem to apply or extend when *someone else* is receiving the tip. I mean, it's not as if the workers from the parable were *reasonably* expecting the master to redistribute the extra payment among them after denying it to the latecomers. The only *logical or plausible* outcome would have been their fellow workers receiving less payment, while theirs would have remained the same. A pointless and disgusting exercise in envy, jealousy, and resentment.

Comment: Well, he couldn't really ask for change for a penny!

Comment: @NigelJ The early employees presumably would have rathered lounge about in the shade and be paid $1. So for them its not about being productive or not, but being paid. If the landowner had come up to them and said "I will pay you $1 for any amount of the day you work" and they still worked the full day, then the landowner would have been completely upfront about the situation.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg The situation changed during the course of the day. Workers were hired but there were still outstanding tasks as the day progressed. Each worker got exactly what had been negotiated as a contract. Nobody forced them into the contract.

Comment: @NigelJ All you say is true. Let's say you are in front of the line to purchase a mobile phone. You ask how much it is. The salesperson says "$100". You agree to pay this. You then step to the side. The next person asks how much it is for the same phone. The salesperson says "$50". Would you feel a bit miffed? "Excuse me, you just told me it's $100." "Oh, well, it's later in the day. You agreed to the price, what's the problem?"

Comment: @AnthonyBurg I repeat, nobody is forced into such contracts. If food prices go up, I either starve or pay the price.

Comment: @NigelJ No disagreement here - no one is forced. The issue I am raising is disclosure of relevant info to the parties. It is relevant to the early workers to know they could work just 1 hour and still get $1. This isn't disclosed by the landowner. In some sense, this isn't fair. Indeed, I think one of the points of the parable is that God isn't 'fair' by typical human metrics, just as loving one's enemies isn't 'fair', giving one's cloak to one who demands one's coat isn't 'fair', and so on. When the landowner says it's 'fair', there is a slightly different meaning intended here, IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us be very clear about this, the parable well illustrates God, very fortunately for us, is NOT fair at all.  God is supremely generous and that is the point being made in the parable of Matt 20:1-16.

The workers were given the wages they had agreed and then so much more.  Before commenting on the parable, let us remind ourselves of what is called the great "Divine Exchange":

- 2 Cor 5:21, God made him who had no sin to be sin for us, so that in him we might become the righteousness of God.
- Gal 1:4, who gave himself for our sins to rescue us from the present evil age, according to the will of our God and Father.
- Isa 53:4, 5, Surely He took on our infirmities and carried our sorrows; yet we considered Him stricken by God, struck down and afflicted.  But He was pierced for our transgressions, He was crushed for our iniquities; the punishment that brought us peace was upon Him, and by His stripes we are healed.

That is, Jesus was treated as we deserve so that we might be treated as He deserves.  Let there be no doubt that this exchange is supremely unfair.  I am glad about that!

Now back to the parable of the vineyard.  I believe the parable of the vineyard shows several things:

- God's grace - were given and rewarded with much more than we deserve.
- God's grace is not limited by our human effort
- Citizens of the kingdom of heaven (Christians) are often called upon to work hard and endure difficult trials.  This effect is very uneven.  However, we will all, alike, be rewarded with a place in the eternal kingdom of God.
- In order to receive the wages, the workers had to agree to go into the field and work; some for a long time and others for a short time.
- God's generosity as expressed in (among other things) His grace often arouses the suspicion of those in the community of Christians (V12, 13)
- The values of this world do not correspond to the values of the kingdom of heaven (v16) - things often appear backwards, upside down, etc, to our earthly, human logic.

Comment: For parallel, see the story of the Prodigal Son. In both those cases, though, it seems the first-workers/elder son doesn't *get* it, and so in some sense is spiritually out of sorts. Hence, the first shall be last and the last first - in the parable of the vineyard, the last workers are paid first.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg - many thanks - good points.

Comment: +For highlighting that God's generosity might seem unfair to us humans but that it is a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

What the parable exposes is that the kingdom of heaven is nothing like earthly kingdoms and that the work of faith and labour of love is not done for hire or reward and that the Lord of the harvest does not count one above another as to exertion.

All the prospective labourers were gathered in the beginning of the day to make themselves available for a day's hire. Some stood idle, unhired, unwanted, until the last hour. Some laboured all day long, in the heat. All got the same pay.

God said to Abraham :

> Fear not, I am thy shield and **thy exceeding great reward**. [Genesis 15:1 KJV]

The reward of knowing God . . . .  is to know God.

Some will labour a lifetime, endure all kinds of afflictions, will be persecuted and hated and ill-treated for decades.

Some will live a comparatively calm life in quiet circumstances.

All will have the same reward :

> And this is life eternal, **that they might know thee the only true God**, and Jesus Christ, whom thou hast sent.

To know God, and his Son Jesus Christ, and to do so eternally . . .  is worth it all, whatever it takes.

And there is no greater reward possible.

All will receive the absolute maximum possible.

*There's nothing more can possibly be given to the labourers who started earlier.*

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the translation of the word you quoted as ‘fair’. The original Greek word is ‘dikaios’ which more literally means ‘right’, as in righteous.
So, was the owner doing the right thing giving all workers the same amount, that is, was he being righteous? Biblically, Righteousness does not equate with our understanding of ‘fairness’.

So, for example, seeing we are discussing a parable, we see parables where one gets 10, another 2, and another 1 - as opposed to everybody getting the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the landowner, knowing that there were going to be complaints at the end of the day, should have met with each employee privately and paid them privately.  In today's society, on payday employers typically would not announce to everybody what everybody was getting paid that day.

Comment: :) so you think, with the 'landowner' being 'God', you might have some advice for him?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't exactly say that.